# Using Import and sub psudo function return error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I have the following cloudformation code:

```
  usagePlan:
Type: AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlan
Properties:
  ApiStages:
  - ApiId: !ImportValue: "test-restApi-lambda-send-email-contactus-post"
    Stage: "stg1"
  Description: Customer ABC's usage plan
  Quota:
    Limit: 5000
    Period: MONTH
  Throttle:
    BurstLimit: 200
    RateLimit: 100
  UsagePlanName: Plan_ABC
```

everything is fine and the code is working.
As soon as I turn it to :

```
  usagePlan:
Type: AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlan
Properties:
  ApiStages:
  - ApiId:
    Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${project}-restApi-lambda-send-email-contactus-post"
    Stage: "stg1"
  Description: Customer ABC's usage plan
  Quota:
    Limit: 5000
    Period: MONTH
  Throttle:
    BurstLimit: 200
    RateLimit: 100
  UsagePlanName: Plan_ABC
```

I get the following error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: [/Resources/usagePlan/Type/ApiStages/0/ApiId] 'null' values are not allowed in templates
```

The problem exactly happens at this stage:

```
Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${project}-restApi-lambda-send-email-contactus-post"
```

Any idea? is it a bug in aws?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a tab before `Fn::ImportValue`:

This should work:

```
ApiStages:
  - ApiId:
      Fn::ImportValue: !Sub "${project}-restApi-lambda-send-email-contactus-post"
```